# chart.js Radar Chart min/max issue

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to do a simple radar chart in chart.js v4 with 0 as center and 6 as highest point. However all i get is the center being somewhere between 0 and 3 (depending on what my lowest value in the dataset is) and the max being somewhere between 5 and 6. I am kind of lost what might cause this. I tried the following config that sets min 0 and max 6 as well as beginAtZero to true. Any ideas? Thanks

```
const config = {
            type: 'radar',
            data: {
                //labels: labels,
                labels: data,
                datasets: [{
                    data: data,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.36)',
                    borderColor: 'white',
                    borderWidth: 3
                }]
            },
            options: {
                plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    }
                },
                scales: {
                    r: {
                        angleLines: {
                            display: true
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            min: 0,
                            max: 6,
                            stepSize: 1,
                            color: 'black',
                            font: {
                                size: 20
                            }
                        },
                        pointLabels: {
                            color: 'black',
                            font: {
                                size: 20
                            },
                            backdropColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)',
                            backdropPadding: 6
                        },
                        // Ensure that the grid lines also start from 0 if necessary
                        grid: {
                            circular: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                elements: {
                    line: {
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
                    }
                },
            }
        };

        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        new Chart(ctx, config);
```

Comment: You may set [`beginAtZero: true`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html#linear-radial-axis-specific-options). Note that you have misplaced your `beginAtZero` option - it is (in newer versions of chart.js) an option of the axis, not of the ticks. Setting `min: 0` also works, again under `options.scales.r` and not under `options.scales.r.ticks`.